# Is there any alternative to bubble_overlay in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'd like to create a bubble overlay for my Flutter app...

Through Google, I found the package bubble_overlay and it is discontinued now... So is there any alternative or any other way to implement bubble overlay for Android devices in Flutter???

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you are looking for? https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview

Comment: It looks exactly like chat bubble... but the one you suggested is for showcasing the existing widgets inside the app...

Comment: In your question you are not saying what you want to achieve and the documentation for the package your refer to is pretty poor. Hence I guessed.